# Capturing Data Usage

Tags: java, blackberry

What classes are available in the blackberry API that can be used to capture information on the data usage on the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [RadioInfo](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/RadioInfo.html) class has a few methods that might be handy, such as `getNumberOfPacketsReceived()` and `getNumberOfPacketsSent()`

Comment: Thanks. Just the kind of thing i'm looking for